# URI creation best practice

Tags: offchain-worker

What is the best practice to create a URI in an off-chain worker hook? The `String` and `format!` usage is discouraged. But what is the most convenient way to create a URI from given parts like hostname, path, and maybe query parameters or a request body?

Answer (score 1):

Because a lot of crates or specs are using `&str` as the `uri` argument. I suggest still using `String` in OCW. You just need to write `extern crate alloc;` and `use alloc::string::String`.